# Checkbox Eval to image

Tags: asp.net, database, checkbox

Hi i am doing a portfolio site for myself, and therefore want do display for the users of the site, what i have 'Coded' and what i have 'Designed'. For that i have two checkboxes in my backend, and what i need is, that when a box is checked it should Eval an image from the database (From my 'Create site' to my 'Show site').

asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxCoded" runat="server"

here is my very simple checkbox from the create site, but how should the codebehind look? should i use a bool or what? I am very sorry for my lack of experience, and i hope the question is understandable, and that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the Checkbox events with a checkbox handler in the codebehind, something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxCoded_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles CheckBoxCoded.CheckedChanged
....
End Sub
```